# „Vorstellen" als modalverbähnliches Verb?

Tags: vocabulary, modal-verb

Ich weiß, dass man Sätze mit [modalverbähnlichen Verben](https://sprachekulturkommunikation.com/modalverbaehnliche-verben-mit-infinitiv/) der Wahrnehmung (z.B., sehen, hören, usw.) formulieren kann:

> Ich habe den Mann lachen hören/gehört

Gilt „vorstellen" als solches Verb?

> Ich habe mir den Mann lachen vorgestellt.

Mit „vorstellen" würde man das Partizip, nicht den Infinitiv verwenden müssen.  Aber ich weiß nicht, ob das überhaupt korrekt ist.  Oder muss es das Gerundium sein?

> Ich habe mir den Mann lachend vorgestellt.

(Aber wer lacht hier, der Mann oder ich?)

Comment: Es ist auch im Englischen an dieser Stelle nicht das gerund, sondern das present participle. Beide sind nicht anhand der Form unterscheidbar, sondern nur daran, ob an der Stelle ein Substantiv erwartet wird oder ein Adjektiv. Im Deutschen stellt sich die Frage nicht, da das Deutsche kein Gerundium kennt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nein, *sich vorstellen* kann nicht mit einem Infinitiv in derselben Weise verwendet werden, wie das mit Modalverben oder auch *sehen* oder *hören* möglich ist.

*Ich stelle mir den Mann lachen vor* ist kein grammatikalisch gültiger Satz.

*Vorstellen* kann mit Partizip I (nicht Gerundium, dieses existiert im Neuhochdeutschen nicht) verwendet werden, wie in dem Satz *Ich habe mir den Mann lachend vorgestellt*.

Auch Partizip II ist mit transitiven Verben möglich: *Ich stelle mir den Mann aufgeregt vor*. Aber das ist syntaktisch etwas anderes als die Konstruktion mit Infinitiv.

Answer (score 4):

Ob die von dir vorgeschlagenen Sätze falsch oder richtig sind, ist nicht so einfach zu entscheiden.

Prinzipiell ist es möglich, auch Verben wie *denken* oder *vorstellen* als Verben einer inneren oder imaginären Wahrnehmung zu interpretieren, aber in der Alltagssprache ist das nicht üblich. Man findet solche Konstruktionen eher in der literarischen Sprache, wenn ein Autor in seinen Texten mit Sprache experimentiert, was vom Publikum oftmals auch sehr wohlwollend zur Kenntnis genommen wird. Das ist, wie wenn ein Koch in einem sehr teuren und exquisiten Restaurant ein besonders raffiniertes Gericht kreiert und seinen Gästen serviert. In so einer Umgebung erwartet man ungewöhnliche Kompositionen, die mit Bedacht und Können zusammengestellt wurden.

Aber die meisten Menschen essen nicht, um die besonderen Nuancen einer experimentellen Küche zu genießen, sondern um satt zu werden. Und dem Sattessen entspricht die gewöhnliche Gebrauchssprache, derer wir uns im Alltag bedienen. Und da sollte man eher nicht allzu häufig ausloten, wo genau die Grenzen der deutschen Grammatik liegen. Daher würde ich im Alltag solche Konstruktionen vermeiden. Stattdessen würde ich so etwas vorschlagen:

> Ich habe mir vorgestellt, dass der Mann lacht.
> Ich habe mir vorgestellt, wie der Mann lacht.

Auch das ist korrekt:

> Ich habe mir den Mann lachend vorgestellt.

Aber das ist kein Gerundium. Das Gerundium gibt es in vielen Sprachen. Es ist ein Begriff, der aus der Grammatik der Sprache Latein stammt und dort Verbalsubstantive beschreibt (*»ars vivendi«* = *die Kunst zu Leben* oder *die Kunst des Lebens*; dabei ist *»vivendi«* ein Gerundium). Im Englischen bezeichnet man mit Gerundium ebenfalls ein Verbalsubstantiv, das durch Anhängen des Suffix *-ing* gebildet wird (*»the art of living«* im Gegensatz zu *»the art of life«,* was das Gegenstück der deutschen Konstruktion wäre).

Das Gerundium gibt es mit ähnlicher Funktion auch in den meisten slawischen Sprachen und in einigen anderen Sprachen. In der deutschen Sprache ist das Gerundium aber ungefähr beim Übergang von Mittelhochdeutsch zu Neuhochdeutsch in den meisten Regionen des deutschen Sprachraums verschwunden. Es existiert gegenwärtig nur noch in einigen Dialekten, nicht aber in der deutschen Standardsprache.

Das Verb *lachend* in *»Ich habe mir den Mann lachend vorgestellt«* ist ein Partizip, kein Gerundium. Es ist ein Partizip I, das manchmal auch als "Partizip Präsens" bezeichnet wird. Daneben gibt es das Partizip II, das man auch als "Partizip Perfekt" bezeichnet. (Im Fall des Verbs *lachen* fällt es mir schwer, einen Beispielsatz für Partizip II zu bilden, daher verwende ich ein anderes Verb, nämlich *schreiben:* Partizip I: *»Der schreibende Mann denkt nach.« »Ich habe den Mann schreibend vorgefunden.«* Partizip II: *»Das geschriebene Wort ist bedeutsamer.« »Ich habe diesen Satz nicht nur gehört, sondern auch geschrieben gesehen.«*)

Wer lacht in dem Satz *»Ich habe mir den Mann lachend vorgestellt«*? Das kann ich sein, das kann aber auch der Mann sein. Das ist unklar und kann ohne Kontext nicht entschieden werden. Sprache ist oft mehrdeutig.

Comment: Ich denke eine gute Antwort, aber mit dem Essen, um satt zu werden, habe ich Bauchschmerzen, die auch auf's Sprechen/Schreiben übertragen werden müssen. Essen, wenn es in Gemeinschaft stattfindet (meist Partnerschaft, Familie) ist dann auch ein soziales Ereignis. Satt würden wir auch mit 3 Scheiben trocken Brot. In die Vorbereitung des Essens (Einkauf/geh'n wir zum Italiener?) fließen mannigfaltige Motive ein (Gesundheit, Abwechslung, Geschmack, ...) und auch unser sprachlicher Ausdruck wird von zig kontextabhängigen Motiven begleitet. "Gewöhnliche Gebrauchssprache" ist kein hilfreicher Rat.